# Django Admin: Select foreign key 'children' from 'parent' change view

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models, parent and child (many children to one parent). I'm able to add new children to a parent in the parent change view, but I want to be able to bulk add existing parentless children to the parent, similar to the filter_horizontal option for many-to-many fields.

My models look roughly like:

```
#models.py

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

#admin.py

class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child

@admin.register(Parent)
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildInline,]
```

I was thinking of using a many-to-many relationship instead and using filter_horizontal, but I want to make sure one child only has one parent and the filter_horizontal list only shows parentless children, which I'm not sure how to do.